# Error while adding a user in Phoenix App - Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am a newbie in Elixir and Phoenix and I was trying out a sample user validation app in phoenix. Below in the following code

Module TestApp.Users.User
......

```
def changeset(%User{} = user, attrs) do
user
|> cast(attrs, [:username, :email])
|> validate_required([:username, :email])
|> unique_constraint(:username)
|> unique_constraint(:email)
end

def registration_changeset(%User{} = user, attrs) do
user
|> changeset(attrs)
|> cast(attrs, [:password])
|> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
|> put_password_hash()
end

defp put_password_hash(changeset) do
case changeset do
  %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: password}} ->
    put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password))
  _ ->
    changeset
end
end
```

Module TestApp.Users
....

```
def create_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
%User{}
|> User.registration_changeset(attrs)
|> Repo.insert()
end
```

Migration File

```
def change do
create table(:users) do
  add :username, :string, null: false
  add :email, :string, null: false
  add :password, :string, virtual: true
  add :password_hash, :string, null: false

  timestamps()
end

create unique_index(:users, [:username])
create unique_index(:users, [:email])
end
```

When I run

```
TestApp.Users.create_user(%{email: "third@user.com", username: "third_user", password: "password"})
```

I get

```
** (ArgumentError) unknown field `password`. Only fields, embeds and associations (except :through ones) are supported in changesets
```

Comment: Can you post the `schema "users" do ... end` declaration?

Comment: oh yes the :password field was missing in it, my bad. Thanks